# How do I navigate to a stateful widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter program with 2 stateful widgets I want to switch between, State1 and State2.

I can get it to work if I set State2 as a stateless widget but when I set it to stateful it gives the error "The return type 'State2' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context."

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp (
    const MaterialApp(
      home: MyFlutterApp()
    ),
  );
}

class MyFlutterApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyFlutterApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return State1();
  }
}

class State1 extends State<MyFlutterApp>{

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => State2()));
          },
          child: const Text("State1")
          )
      );
  }
}

class State2 extends State<StatefulWidget> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        child: const Text("State2"),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing state instead of widget in navigator

State2 is extending state object which is associated with stateful widget instead of just stateful widget.

make state2 a stateful widget

```
class MyFlutterApp extends StatefulWidget {
 const MyFlutterApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
   return State1();
 }
}

class State1 extends State<MyFlutterApp>{

 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     body: GestureDetector(
         onTap: () {
           Navigator.of(context).push(CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => State2()));
         },
         child: const Text("State1")
         )
     );
 }
}

class State2 extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
   return _State2State();
 }
}

class _State2State extends State<State2> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     body: GestureDetector(
       child: const Text("State2"),
       onTap: () {
         Navigator.pop(context);
       }
     )
   );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can push/replace the same route passing a parameter, whit this parameter you can make a if for check which state return

```
class MyFlutterApp extends StatefulWidget {
final bool setFirstState;


const MyFlutterApp({Key? key, required this.setFirstState}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    if(firstState){
      return State1();
    } else {
      return State2();
    }
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you only use a stateful widget to manage some kind of changing variable. This means in this example, state 1 and 2 do not need to be stateful. However, your flutterApp widget could manage what screen it wants to display making that a stateful widget. You wouldnt use pageRoute to navigate to these pages, just render them conditionally.

```
class MyFlutterApp extends StatefulWidget {
    const MyFlutterApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyFlutterApp> createState() => _MyFlutterAppState();
}

class _MyFlutterAppState extends State<MyFlutterApp> {
  bool _isState1 = true;

  // getting for each widget
  Widget get _selectedView => _isState1 ? const State1() : const State2();

  void changeView() {
    setState(() {
      _isState1 = !_isState1;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        _selectedView,
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: changeView,
          child: const Text('change view'),
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
}

class State1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const State1({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Center(
      child: Text('child 1'),
    );
  }
}

class State2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const State2({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Center(
      child: Text('child 2'),
    );
  }
}
```